# Excel workbook referencing from cells

Tags: excel

Hi any help would be appreciated, I'm try to reference a workbook address from a cell as follows:

`\\SERVER\Documents\Clients\ZZ Control Sheets\TEST\[A69.xlsx]2019'!$B$6`

This works fine, returns contents of `B6` from sheet `2019` in workbook `A69.xlsx`.

Because I'm working with a lot of sheets and cells I need to put the A69 part in a cell and reference the address from that. EG I put A69 in cell A9 and want something like:

`='\\SERVER\Documents\Clients\ZZ Control Sheets\TEST\[(=INDIRECT(A9) & ".xlsx")]2019'!$B$6`

or

`='\\SERVER\Documents\Clients\ZZ Control Sheets\TEST\[=A9 & ".xlsx"]2019'!$B$6`

Something along those lines anyway, but can't find anything that will work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the file path within a string (enclosed in `"`) and break out of the string to reference cell A9.

`="'\SERVER\Documents\Clients\ZZ Control Sheets\TEST[" & A9 & ".xlsx]2019'!$B$6"`

will return

`'\SERVER\Documents\Clients\ZZ Control Sheets\TEST[A69.xlsx]2019'!$B$6`

The important bit is:  `"…." & A9 & "…"`.  Note the only `=` sign is at the beginning of the formula.